# regex validations for textarea angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex

I would like to validate a my textarea field using regex in my angular app.  but their will be a certain conditions for textarea.

    1. Message should not be more than 500 characters.
    2. Text should not consecutive space characters.
    3. No word should be more than 20 characters.
    4. There should not be consecutive special characters.

```
<textarea id="message" name="message" type="text" placeholder="" required="" ng-maxlength="500" ng-model="message" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$/" class="form-control"></textarea>
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, how do you using ng-pattern to validate this regex? Please help me to display a message whether the input is not in the desired format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. done `ng-maxlength="500"`
2. \x20{1}/g - not consecutive space characters
3. \W{20,}/g - no word at least 20 chars
4. [^\s]{1}/g - not be consecutive special characters

try this `ng-pattern="/(\W{20,}|\x20{1}|[^\s]{1})/g"`